# Pandas Group By and Sum Every N rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have time series data and I want to group by and calculate the sum every 3 rows. Seems like a straightforward task but I'm not able to figure it out. I would appreciate your help.

Below is the data:

```
df = 
                      AE_NAME  ANSWERED_CALL
    DATE                                    
    2018-10-08  Alec Sochacki            4.0
    2018-10-09  Alec Sochacki            4.0
    2018-10-10  Alec Sochacki            7.0
    2018-10-11  Alec Sochacki            5.0
    2018-10-12  Alec Sochacki            3.0
    2018-10-15  Alec Sochacki            4.0
    2018-10-16  Alec Sochacki            3.0
    2018-10-17  Alec Sochacki            8.0
    2018-10-18  Alec Sochacki            5.0
    2018-10-19  Alec Sochacki            7.0
```

Column `Date` is an index column.

I want the output to be as follows:

```
                  AE_NAME  ANSWERED_CALL
DATE                                    
2018-10-08  Alec Sochacki            0 # It's ok to omit the first row
2018-10-10  Alec Sochacki            15
2018-10-15  Alec Sochacki            12
2018-10-18  Alec Sochacki            16
2018-10-19  Alec Sochacki            7
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First elevate your index to a series. Then use `groupby` + `agg` with a dictionary:

```
df = df.reset_index()

d = {'DATE': 'last', 'AE_NAME': 'last', 'ANSWERED_CALL': 'sum'}

res = df.groupby(df.index // 3).agg(d)

print(res)

        DATE       AE_NAME  ANSWERED_CALL
0 2018-10-10  AlecSochacki           15.0
1 2018-10-15  AlecSochacki           12.0
2 2018-10-18  AlecSochacki           16.0
3 2018-10-19  AlecSochacki            7.0
```

You've got some unclear logic for the first row, so you may need one or two more operations.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have provided an example with just one `AE_NAME`. I don't think this will work when I have multiple `AE_NAME`. Would I now require I `groupby` on the `AE_NAME` and then sum every three rows?

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal, Unfortunately, I don't know what you expect. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53179216/edit) to include multiple names and your desired output?