# Pandas GroupBy ["A"] Every Nth Row of ["B"] and Compute Difference of ["C"]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that represents several different machine `ids`, their `job` number, and the `value` they output, as follows:

```
     id  job  value
0     1    1     42
1     1    2     42
2     1    3     42
3     1    4     45
4     2    1     38
5     2    2     38
6     2    3     40
7     2    4     40
8     2    5     42
9     3    1     44
10    3    2     44
11    3    3     43
12    3    4     43
```

A machine gets each job done in 20 seconds. My goal is to know **how many times the value changed per minute**. For example, the intermediate step dataframe would be as follows:

```
     id  changes
0     1        0  # jobs 1-3=60 seconds. No changes in value
1     1        1  # job 4. Changed from previous value
2     2        1  # jobs 1-3. One change
3     2        1  # jobs 4-5. One change
4     3        1  # jobs 1-3. One change
5     3        0  # job 4. No changes
```

Then I can easily calculate the end result (change rate per minute) summing the changes column and divide by the number of entries.

```
     id  rate
0     1   0.5
1     2   1.0
2     3   0.5
```

I looked at other questions that partially answer mine, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179216/pandas-group-by-and-sum-every-n-rows) that uses `df.groupby(df.index // 3)` to do the bins, but in my case I want that grouping to be per id (`groupby(df["id"] // 3)`?). And `df['changes'] = df.col1 - df.col1.shift()`?

Edit to add more test cases:

```py
# Values start at zero to indicate when changes happen
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
            "job": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
            "value": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
        }
    )
```

Expected result is

```py
1    2.5 # 5 changes total over two minutes
2    0.0 # 0 changes total over one minute
3    1.0 # 2 changes total over a minute and 20 seconds (2 periods)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @quang hoang answer, I was able to reach my goal. Here's my code:

```py
JOB_DURATION_SECONDS = 10
print(df)

# Compute the number of changes
df["num_of_changes"] = df.groupby("id").value.apply(
    lambda x: x.rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] < x.iloc[1])
)
print(df)

# Group by id and calculate rate per minute
out = (
    df[["id", "num_of_changes"]]
    .groupby(["id"])
    .apply(lambda x: x["num_of_changes"].sum() / (len(x) * JOB_DURATION_SECONDS))
)
print(out)
```

Resulting in

```
# Input
         id  job            value
0         1    1                0
1         1    2                1
2         1    3                2
3         1    4                3
4         1    5                4
5         1    6                5
6         2    1                0
7         2    2                0
8         2    3                0
9         3    1                0
10        3    2                0
11        3    3                1
12        3    4                1
13        3    5                1
14        3    6                1
15        3    7                1

# Intermediate
         id  job            value  num_of_changes
0         1    1                0             NaN
1         1    2                1             1.0
2         1    3                2             1.0
3         1    4                3             1.0
4         1    5                4             1.0
5         1    6                5             1.0
6         2    1                0             NaN
7         2    2                0             0.0
8         2    3                0             0.0
9         3    1                0             NaN
10        3    2                0             0.0
11        3    3                1             1.0
12        3    4                1             0.0
13        3    5                1             0.0
14        3    6                1             0.0
15        3    7                1             0.0

# Out
id
1    5.000000
2    0.000000
3    0.857143
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby().rolling()` to group the rows, then compare the max and min to know whether the value has changed:

```
rolling = df.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(3)

intermediate = rolling.max().dropna() != rolling.min().dropna()

out = intermediate.groupby('id').mean()
```

Output (intermediate):

```
id    
1   2     False
    3      True
2   6      True
    7      True
    8      True
3   11     True
    12     True
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Output:

```
id
1    0.5
2    1.0
3    1.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost gets the job done, but I found one issue with the rolling window. I added another test case to illustrate. In the case where we have all changes, the solution does not capture all the changes

Comment: Adding `.rolling(3, min_periods=1, closed="both")` improves the intermediate df. The third case still wrong as we are comparing min and max from rolling window: `0, 1, 1, 2` return `False, True, True, True` which would evaluate to three changes instead of two